# Is there a way to see invisible characters that are in my file using Python or Bash?

Tags: python, bash, command-line, escaping

I have a bug that is causing return statements in my output file, but I am not sure if they are already in my input file or if they are caused by my code. I have tried stripping my lines already. Can anyone point me to how to see the "\t", "\n" or spaces ("  ") if they might be there?  Any help would be great.  Thank you! Bash or Python would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [cat from coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cat-invocation.html#cat-invocation):

```
cat -A file
```

or

```
cat -v file
```

Comment: Thank you. I did see this at some point, but why is this not "concatenate"?  Does it just do different things depending on the argument you give it?

Comment: **cat** is the UNIX command to concatenate a file to *stdout*.  From your shell (bash) command line, type **man cat** for details.

Comment: @Prune, thank you for the man command. I have spent a lot of time learning random shell/bash commands, but not one told me about "man". Wow. Very important!!

Comment: Obviously, you didn't take "Intro to UNIX" from *me*.  :-)  I also suggest the O'Reilly book "UNIX in a Nutshell".  My copy still sits on my desk at work.  It's great to leaf through and learn new things, even after several decades on UNIX.

Comment: It does say "cat -A" is an illegal command. Does argument not always exist?  "cat -v" did work.

Comment: @jennifer06262016: Your `cat` is probably not from coreutils.

Comment: Nice, but if your non-GNU `cat` supports `-v`, it probably also supports `-et`, which is the true equivalent of `cat -A` (`-v` will not show tabs, and it will not show line endings).

Answer (score 0):

cat file | grep -F "\t"

substitute "\f" for whatever you are searching for.

-F interprets "PATTERN" as fixed string.